# Add Properties to Features in GeoJSON Feature Collection with Python

Tags: python, geojson

I have a GeoJSON feature collection that is solely linestrings of trips. I'd like to add both lists  and dictionaries to each feature. The data being added to each feature is different for each feature, but is stored the same order as the routes. How can I add this data as properties to the Feature Collection?

```
type(data)
>>> geojson.feature.FeatureCollection

data[1] #Example of what the data looks like
{'type': 'Feature',
 'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
  'coordinates': [[-94.579644, 39.102126],
   [-64.579644, 29.102126],
   [-64.52684, 29.112103],
   [-64.52684, 29.112103]]},
 'properties': {'name': 'Route #1'}}
```

And example of the data I want to add is below. I'd like the Trip_ID for this trip to become a property in the Feature Collection, above.

```
type(Trip_ID)
...list

trip_id[1]
'149b16a4-f1ee-40ce-a165-5326196a1307'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add each of the IDs in the `Trip_ID` collection to each of your Feature objects in the FeatureCollection.

I would have tried :

```
for i in range(len(Trip_ID)):
    data[i].properties['id'] = Trip_ID[i]
```

**Note:** Assuming both collections are of same size and order.

Comment: Nice! This got me close enough to get it! The data is indeed the same length and order, so this works very nicely!

I had to make it a little more complicated due to the very nested nature of the geojson object (multiple nested dictionaries inside it). 

`for i in range(len(trip_id)):
    data['features'][i]['properties']['id'] = trip_id[i]`